# _ComObject Error while access Vb6 object in c#

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, vb6

I had one Menulist in Vb6 so Iam Trying to add Recent File Names in this Menu list through C#.net dll So Iam Passing this Menulist  as an object in .net dll But when I tried to access the object it is showing _ComObject Please help

Comment: Manipulating the VB6 UI object model from .net would NOT be a path I'd recommend. Best case you could figure out how to create a com interop assembly for the VB6 types (not even sure if they expose enough of the VB6 internals as COM libraries to do so). Likely case is you'd have to use a dispatch interface in .net which would be pretty labor intensive. Were someone to ask me to do this I'd run away.

Comment: thanks sir for response but Sir Is their a way if i Add recent File name in a c# collectionn and return it to vb6 Collection